# Simple Powershell 7.0 Script

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have been practicing Powershell for a few days. I am trying to create a script to pull all
of the files with the extension .ps1 from my desktop and copy them to a folder in my documents.

It is a simple script and only slightly useful but I am doing it as a exercise.
I have been trying to get this to work on and off for the last two days but it
seems to get hung up. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I will post the few different
ways I have tried to get this to work. All of the scripts I see floating around for
this are much more complex and I am just trying to start small and build from there.

Sample 1:

```
$dir = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\*"
$des = "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Scripts\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -File | 
    Where-Object -Property Extension -eq ".ps1" |
        Copy-Item -Destination $des
```

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\Me> Copy-Item: untitled:Untitled-2:6:9
Line |
   6 |          Copy-Item -Destination $des
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Could not find file 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\Scripts\Update-Help.ps1'.
```

Sample 2:

```
$dir = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\*"
$des = "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Scripts\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse -Force |
    Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq '.ps1'} | #This seems to return what I need to copy.
        Copy-Item -Destination $des
```

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\Me>
    Directory: C:\Users\Me\Desktop

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          11/18/2020 10:40 PM            172 Update-Help.ps1

    Directory: C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Desktop\kon-bootUSB

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          10/30/2018  2:30 PM            351 auto.ps1

PS C:\Users\Me> Copy-Item: untitled:Untitled-2:11:9
Line |
  11 |          Copy-Item -Destination $des
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Could not find file 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\Scripts\Update-Help.ps1'.

Copy-Item: untitled:Untitled-2:11:9
Line |
  11 |          Copy-Item -Destination $des
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Could not find file 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\Scripts\auto.ps1'.
```

Any thoughts on what I am missing would be very helpful!
I have tried to move things around and resort to the help
pages for the commands.

Comment: Do you have files with colons in the names?

Comment: @js2010, No I do not. They are named with a typical naming convection. Still getting the same error with the below solution. I am not sure if it is the script at this point. I have tried it may ways. I have made sure it is grabbing the files I need by just running the Get-ChildItem and it returns the files I want to copy but is having a hard time copying them for some reason. As far ad I know, my Copy-Item syntax seems correct. The -Path does not have to be included, correct? I just want to copy the output of the previous pipe and use that for the copy statement.

Comment: What is `untitled:Untitled-2:11:9`?

Comment: I have searched for that on my computer and it does not come back with anything. I have noticed it appends that to my .ps1 files though ":6:9"

Comment: I only see that if I grab it with script though.

Comment: Does the destination exist?  `C:\Users\Me\Documents\Scripts`

Comment: Yes, it exists as a folder in my Documents directory. I copied the path from file explorer.

Comment: I can list the items in it with Get-ChildItem. That is true for both paths.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain but the `Where-Object` could be causing problems, you can eliminate that and use the native `-Filter` parameter of `Get-ChildItem`.

Try

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.ps1 -Path $dir | Copy-Item -Destination $des
```

I would also eliminate the `*` component of your `$dir` variable

Comment: This is one of the earlier things I tried, then I added Where-Object and even tried Select-Object and am coming to the same blockade. Thank you for your help!